# String input in mips is not read as the way I read it when I set its value in data segment

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data
val:  .space 64
ask1:  .asciiz "\nEnter input number base(2-16): "  
ask2:  .asciiz "\nEnter a value of that base: "
ask3:  .asciiz "\nEnter output number base(2-16): "
result:  .asciiz "\nThe result is: "
line: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main
main:

la      $a0, ask1           #ask for input number base
li      $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5                   # syscall 5 to read the int, store in $v0
syscall                     # actually read the int
move $t1, $v0               # store input(number base) in $t1.

la      $a0, ask2           #ask for input value
li      $v0, 4
syscall

li      $v0, 8              #read the input value
la      $a0, val
la      $a1, 64
syscall

li      $v0, 4
syscall 

la      $a0, ask3           #ask for output number base
li      $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5                   # syscall 5 to read the int, store in $v0
syscall                     # actually read the int
move $t5, $v0               # store output(number base) in $t5.

li      $t2,0       #counter
li      $t3,0       #sum
li      $t4,1       #power
li      $s1,65      #asciiz code of "A"
li      $s2,10      #for converting int to string in getStrVal

#t5=o.base, t1=i.base

getLength:                      #getting length of string
lb      $t0, val($t2)       
add     $t2, $t2, 1         #t2 = length of string
bne     $t0, $zero, getLength

sub     $t2, $t2, 1     #adjust t2

#get lowest place value
sub     $t2, $t2, 1         #counter--
la      $t0, val($t2)       #load address
lb      $a0, ($t0)          #load character to a0
```

The program in the above is a part of a program to let user input a number of base(2-16) to convert it to another base(2-16).

When I was programming, I set val to be something like this val: .asciiz "A123".

It works well when I access it like this

```
#get lowest place value
sub     $t2, $t2, 1         #counter--
la      $t0, val($t2)       #load address
lb      $a0, ($t0)          #load character to a0
```

However when I change it to ask users to input a String into val, I cant use the way above to access the String byte by byte anymore ($a0 does not return the correct value).

May I ask why and how can I fix this?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug it?

Comment: I tried to print the string val after i input something in it, it prints out what i type, but i cant access it

Comment: I have tried input "A" in the string, 16 as input base, 2 as output base, but the first byte returned($a0) is of value 0000000a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the string input by the user contains the line feed ASCII character (0xA).

Therefore you should subtract 2 instead of 1 in the line which issues

```
   sub     $t2, $t2, 1     #adjust t2
```

e.g.:

```
   sub     $t2, $t2, 2     #adjust t2 taking into account line feed character in user input
```